# If wild shape ends by falling to 0 hp, does the druid lose concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, druid, wild-shape, concentration

A druid that is wild shaped reverts "when" they drop to 0 hit points.  Does that mean other effects that occur when a creature drops to 0 hit points also occur (though possibly in any order of the druid's choice)?  Specifically, if the druid were concentrating on a spell, would dropping to 0 hp - even momentarily - suffice to cause the druid to lose concentration by being incapacitated?

I can't figure out what RAW or RAI is on this one - does anybody have any pointers (e.g. a rule or rule interaction I missed, or some sage advice)?

Comment: Thanks for the link; the relevant bit being the rule that "As long as the excess damage doesn’t reduce your normal form to 0 hit points, you aren’t knocked unconscious."